# Choose $a$ and $b$ such that the integral converges - verification

Tags: integration, analysis, proof-verification

I have posted this question earlier but I would like some input on my own solution so that I have not left anything out that makes it less rigorous.

Find $a$ and $b$ so that the integral $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x}{(x-1)^a(1+x^2)^b}\, dx$$ converges. My attempt:

---

Make change of variable  $t=x-1$, note the change of lower limit:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^a(t^2+2t+2)^b}\, dt =
  \int_0^1 \frac{t+1}{t^a(t^2+2t+2)^b}\, dt +
  \int_1^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^a(t^2+2t+2)^b}\, dt$$

The integral is split into two and let's start by looking at the first part and have the limits in mind. We can then say

$$t^2+2t+2<6 \quad \forall t: \ 0\leq t\leq 1\\
  \Rightarrow
  \int_0^1 \frac{t+1}{t^a(t^2+2t+2)^b}\, dt <
  \frac{1}{6^b}\int_0^1 \frac{t+1}{t^a}\, dt =
  \frac{1}{6^b}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{t}{t^a}\, dt+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t^a}\, dt\right)$$

$6^{-b}$ is a constant and will not affect the convergence - let us neglect it and observe the following anti-derivatives as well as their limits:

$$\left[\frac{t^{2-a}}{2-a}\right]_0^1+  \left[\frac{t^{1-a}}{1-a}\right]_0^1$$

If $t$ is in the denominator we will have division with $0$ when inserting the lower limit. We deduce that $a<1$. Continue with the second part of the integral:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^a(t^2+2t+2)^b}\, dt < \int_1^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^a (6t^2)^b}\, dt$$

The inequality comes from $t^2+2t+2<6t^2$ $\forall t> 1$, which can easily be verified. Neglect $6^b$ as before:

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{t+1}{t^{2b+a}}\, dt =
  \int_1^\infty \frac{t}{t^{2b+a}}\, dt +
  \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{t^{2b+a}}\, dt$$

According to a well known theorem the integral will converge if and only if $2b+t-1>1$ which gives $b>1-\frac{a}{2}$.

Comment: You want $t^2+2t+2 > 2$ to get an upper bound.

Comment: @marty cohen I'm not sure I'm following, the upper bound is already 1?

Comment: To increase the integral, you need to decrease the denominator, so you want a lower bound, not an upper bound.